# iphone function

Tags: iphone

hi i hav a code like this
in the end i m getting error "the control reaches end of non-void function"
how'll i get rid of this? tell me if anyone has the solution.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
            viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"Callouts here");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of that method states that it returns a pointer to `MKAnnotationView`, so you need to return something after your `NSLog` statement. Try the following:

```
(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {
     NSLog(@"Callouts here"); 
     return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has to return something because you defined a return type.

If you have nothing to return, simply **return nil**, although that can cause problems if the caller doesn't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error is that it's technically possible for your method to finish without returning anything (according to the compiler, anyway).